# FQL Working in Graph API explorer but not in php Code

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have this code:

```
//Create Query
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'access_token' => '$user->accessToken',
    'query' => "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = XXXXXXXX)",
);

//Run Query
$result = $facebook->api($params);

var_dump($result);
```

When i run the script containing above code, I don't get any result. Rather, i get the error Maximum execution time exceeded. 
I have confirmed that the query is ok by checking it in `Graph API Explorer`. Moreover, I have also confirmed (by debugging) that the `$user->accessToken` contains correct access token with all the permissions given by user.

I have also tried using `urlencode` with my query string as well... without any success.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Simple - when you ask a question, if somebody answers it and you feel it is the correct answer, make mark it as such by clicking the checkmark to the upper-left of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're single-quoting your access token reference.

```
'access_token' => '$user->accessToken',
                 ^^^                ^^^
```

That sets the value to, literally `$user->accessToken`. Change the right-side quotes to double quotes (or better yet, remove them altogether).

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but my my original problem turned out to be the proxy-and-curl problem which i have solved. 
Now, I am getting Facebook's Invalid API key exception. Do u know anything regarding it?

Comment: check the `app_id` and `app_secret` that you have provided in your `$facebook` variable